# How to make a click counter where the value doesn't reset

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a click counter where the value doesn't reset when the page is refreshed. I also need it to be a culmination of all clicks from all users, not just one user. So it will, essentially, be one big click counter. Here is my code, but I don't have a great idea of what I am doing.

```
    <!DOCTYPEhtml>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 Clicks:<span id="numClicked"></span><br>
 <button id="button">Click</button>
 </body>
 </html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#button').click(function(){

       $.ajax({
          url: "saveCounter.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
             "action" : "increment"
          }
         }).success(function(data){
              $('#numClicked').html(data);
         }).error(function(){

         });

       });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "saveCounter.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
             "action" : "get"
          }
       }).success(function(data){

           $('#numClicked').html(data);

       }).error(function(){

       });

});
</script>
<?php
if (!isset(GLOBALS["value"])
{
  $GLOBALS["value"] = 0;
}

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "action", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

if ($action !== null)
{
  if ($action == "increment")
  {
     $GLOBALS["value"] += 1;
  }

  echo $GLOBALS["value"];

}
?>
```

Comment: Use [`cookies`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have only tagged javascript and html, I will assume you want to do this using pure javascript, and you do not have access to a server language or storage to implement this. Since you are just tracking clicks, this may be a viable solution. If so, you can use `localStorage`, which will allow you to store a little bit of information in the user's browser so that it will be retained across refresh and browser sessions; however, the user can clear this value if they know how and their count will reset.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f5VG8/6/

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" id="clickButton">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var clicks = 0;

function initiateClicks() {
    var clickStr = localStorage.getItem("clicks");
    if(clickStr == undefined){
        localStorage.setItem("clicks", 0);
        clicks = 0;
    }else{
        clicks = parseInt(clickStr);   
    }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}

function doClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    localStorage.setItem("clicks", clicks);
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}

document.getElementById("clickButton").onclick = doClick;
initiateClicks();
```

What this is doing is loading the click value from the user's browser when the page loads, and writing to it every time that the user clicks. When the user refreshes or exits their browser and then revisits your page later, their click count will be retained provided that the user do not clear the localStorage value you have set. In addition, I believe that localStorage will only work in modern browsers.

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/f5VG8/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the number of click value in your server or cookie

**Soluce 1**

- Make [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request to save dynamically the amount of click on the server
- Load the value saved before on the server

**Javascript**

```
    $('#buttonID').click(function(){

       $.ajax({
          url: "saveCounter.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
             "action" : "increment"
          }
         }).success(function(data){
              $('#numberOfClickContainerID').html(data);
         }).error(function(){

         });

       });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "saveCounter.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
             "action" : "get"
          }
       }).success(function(data){

           $('#numberOfClickContainerID').html(data);

       }).error(function(){

       });

});
```

**php**

```
if (!isset(GLOBALS["value"])
{
  $GLOBALS["value"] = 0;
}

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "action", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

if ($action !== null)
{
  if ($action == "increment")
  {
     $GLOBALS["value"] += 1;
  }

  echo $GLOBALS["value"];

}
```

How everything is working?

- At the page loading (*$(document).ready()*) we call dynamically a php page name saveCounter.php with specific arguments in purpose to get the saved amount of click available on the server.
- We assicioted some action to the button click. When the user click, we call dynamically saveCounter.php to increment the counter value and retrieve the new one.

**Soluce 2**

- Use cookie according to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) tutorial

Comment: when I do this the value still disappears when the page is refreshed

Comment: I must be missing something

Comment: assuming you used method 1 and you are in fact using PHP you still have to retrieve the get parameter and set the value of the anchor `<a><?php echo $_GET['count']; ?></a>`

Comment: How would I use Ajax, can you give me some sample code by any chance? I want the value to be saved for everyone, not just one individual. I want to make it so that everyone can add to it.

Comment: I made some code for you, sorry about ident, hard to code right in there :)

Comment: Thanks, how would I use this with html as well? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: I know I'm basically asking for the finished product, I'm just trying to understand how everything works.

Comment: Check out my edited status, that is how I used the code, and obviously I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: I guess you made it right. Your PHP code is on a file named saveCounter.php?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: did the code work for you? I have both the javascript and php in their own external files(saveCounter.js and saveCounter.php).

Comment: Can you opened developer toolbar in your browser? Did the .php page  be called? What respond?

Comment: You need to run this on apache or a similar web server with php installed in order for this to work, have you done this?

Comment: No, how would I run this in apache?

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 localStorage.

This similar example is on the w3's webpage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
 function onClick() { 
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('clicks')) {
        localStorage.clicks = Number(localStorage.clicks)+1;
    } else {
        localStorage.clicks = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = localStorage.clicks;
 };
```